# Unable to route in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have been leaning AngularJS from e-book of Dan Wahlin. There author tried to explain about Modules, Route and Factories from the page 53. Then, I wrote the code in index.html as:

```
<div class="container" data-ng-app="demoApp">
<div>
    <h3>Adding Module Configuration and Routing</h3>
    <!-- ng-view handles loading partials into it based
         upon routes -->
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/view1',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: urlBase + 'View1.html'
            })
        //Define a route that has a route parameter in it (:customerID)
            .when('/view2',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: urlBase + 'View2.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/View1' });
});

demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
        { name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix' },
        { name: 'Jamie Riley', city: 'Atlanta' },
        { name: 'Heedy Wahlin', city: 'Chandler' },
        { name: 'Thomas Winter', city: 'Seattle' }
    ];
});

$scope.addCustomer = function () {
    $scope.customers.push({ name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city      });
}


</script>
```

Then I created two html pages - `View1.html` and `View2.html` and in the View1.html, I wrote:

```
<div class="container">

    <h3>View 1</h3>

    Name<br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name">
            {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}
        </li>
    </ul>

    <br />Customer Name<br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
    <br />

    <br />Customer City<br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
    <br />

    <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
    <br />
    <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>

</div>
```

When I browse as `http://localhost/angular/index.html#/view1` , I do not see anything that's mean no output. I do not understand actually where I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue here is that you are not including the [routing module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute), which is required since Angular 1.2+

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

//Snip...

</script>
```

As mentioned by [goutham in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701585/unable-to-route-in-angularjs/22701645?noredirect=1#comment34593661_22701645), you also need to define `urlBase` which you do not appear to do anywhere.

Because JavaScript does type coercion for string concatenation, you are going to end up with the word 'undefined' appended to your `templateUrl`.

```
console.log(undefined + "view1.html"); // 'undefinedview1.html'
```

Comment: Also `var base_url = "someUrl" ;` should be added at the top of the config function.

Comment: Thanks @Josh and goutham. Both of your suggestion helped me. Just need to know one thing remained that is I can't add customer now. Could you tell me please.